# Python speech recognition: recognize_google with UnknownValueError for Microphone

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

my question is about the speech recognition using Python. My code is supposed to listen to what I say to the microphone (having 5 seconds to say my message) and then print out whatever it understood.

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()

with mic as audio:
    print("Speak Please")

    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(audio)
    audio = r.record(audio, duration=5)

    print("Converting Speech to Text...")
    print("You said: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
```

But I always get the error message:

```
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 780, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

I tried to use audio files I found online and r.recognize_google worked  fine. But once I use my microphone I always get an error.
I also tried switching between "record" and "listen", without any success.
Has anybody encountered a similar problem and knows what might be wrong?

Edit:
Using an except block like:

```
try:
   print("You said: {}".format(r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-USA')))
except:
   print("Couldn't hear you")
```

Also does not help, it just throws the exception every time.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you try to put language='en' in r.recognize_google

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Thank you for your answer. I tried that, but the error message always stays the same unfortunately.

Comment: have you install pyaudio??

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Yes, portaudio-19.6.0 and pyaudio-0.2.11 are installed

Comment: from documentation or github page use try and except block may be it can help!!

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Thank you. I tried it and updated the question. Unfortunately it still isn't working.

Comment: Use r.listen(audio) and error still persist give indent to try and except block

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Thank you for your help, this wasn't the problem, but my IDE was causing the error. I posted the answer. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve the problem. Apparently it's a problem with Visual Studio Code. I had to run the code from the terminal, and now it is working fine. Im not sure why this is the case, but I'm happy that it is working now.